# Custom Indicator on ExpandableListView Only Last is changing

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement an `ExpandableListView` with custom indicator.
The list is having two groups and 3 childs for each.

The problem is when I click on group1 the indicator doesnot change but if I click on group2 the indicator works well.

I don't know whats going wrong.

I also want to know more about `getTag()` and `setTag()`. How can I access a particular `GroupView` or `ChildView`.

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
            groupname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupNamesTV);
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolderForGroup(groupname , imageView));
            group = (ViewHolderForGroup) convertView.getTag();

        }
        if(isExpanded)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.down);


        }else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.right);
        }

        group.txtView.setText(groupnames.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you're missing the case where convertView is not null, you need to assign imageView in that case :) check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing the case where convertView is not null, you need to assign imageView in that case :)

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
            groupname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupNamesTV);
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolderForGroup(groupname , imageView));
            group = (ViewHolderForGroup) convertView.getTag();

        } else {

            // we have a view previously created, our stuff is in the TAG
            group = (ViewHolderForGroup) convertView.getTag();
            imageView = group.imageView; // or whatever its name is             
        }




        if(isExpanded)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.down);


        }else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.right);
        }

        group.txtView.setText(groupnames.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }
```

The key point here is, `convertview==null` is the worst case, when no view is yet created. You then correctly create all stuff and store it in the TAG. **The tag is just like a box where you can store whatever you want.**

Later on, when the system needs another view, convertView won't be null, **then it's when you access the previously stored stuff in the TAG**, and recover the  `imageView`.

You can further optimize your routine like this:

```
 @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {

                    // all this is very slow, that's why we only do it when
                    // convertView is null, because it's common to all items.
                    // once a view is created, we will reuse this to show another row

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
                    TextView textGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupNamesTV);
                    ImageView imgGroup = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                    convertView.setTag(new ViewHolderForGroup(textGroup, imgGroup));

                } 

                // regardless of convertView is newly created or recycled, the TAG will now always contain the ViewHolder
                ViewHolderForGroup groupHolder = (ViewHolderForGroup) convertView.getTag();

                groupHolder.imageView.setImageResource(isExpanded?R.mipmap.down:R.mipmap.right);
                groupHolder.txtView.setText(groupnames.get(groupPosition));
                return convertView;
            }
```

You see I've switched imageView, group and groupname to be local variables instead of members: This way it's impossible you run into an error like before.